# How prevent angular provider loads many times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I have a provider (I also tried with controller with same results). This is my code:

```
.provider('socketio', function() {
    this.socket = io.connect("//localhost);
    console.log("LISTENING...");

    this.$get = function() { [...] }
});
```

I'm injecting this way:

```
.controller('HeaderCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, login) { [...] }
```

and

```
.factory('login', function($location, socketio, $rootScope) {

    // socketio operations

})
```

But in my console, I see two LOGS, infact, i have two socketio listening each of them with a  event listener. My console is full with doubled messages.

[image: Listening message]

Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: could you show the whole body of `.provider`? what version of angular do you use?

Comment: You can put a breakpoint and in browser console and see the stack trace for some hints.

Answer (score 1):

Providers are meant to be "factories", hence they must not directly build the service they provide but just offer a get method to be called by Angular to get a factory.
Their use is clearly described in the Angular [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide).
So maybe you should move the `io.connect` call inside the `$get` method.